# Do I need a transit visa travelling from London via Canada to the Dominican Republic?

Tags: visas, air-travel, transit, canada, pakistani-citizens

I've got a Pakistani passport and a valid student visa for England. I'm going to travel to the Dominican Republic with a stay of 17 hours at a Canadian airport. Do I need a transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this nifty tool provided by the Canadian authorities](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Pakistan), it seems that Pakistani nationals need a visa if visiting or transiting Canada:

> Country: Pakistan
>
> - You need a visa to visit or transit Canada.
> - Starting December 11, 2013: citizens of your country will need to provide biometrics (fingerprints and photograph) when applying for a visa. Learn more about biometrics.